# как записать 8 байт в RS-485 используя modbus_tk

Tags: python, modbus

К компьютеру по Ethernet подключен преобразователь из Ethernet в RS-485 и далее подключено 3 RS-485 контроллера. Я записываю регистры в контроллеры с помощью pymodbus. Как мне сделать тоже самое с помощью modbus_tk?

```
    from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
    from pymodbus.utilities import computeCRC

    Defaults.Timeout = 0.02
    client = ModbusClient('192.168.0.191', port=9761)
    client.connect()

    builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder()
    data = [0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF]
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[0])
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[1])
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[2])
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[3])
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[4])
    builder.add_8bit_uint(data[5])
    crc = computeCRC(data)
    builder.add_8bit_uint(crc >> 8)
    builder.add_8bit_uint(crc & 0x00FF)
    payload = builder.build()
    address = 0
    client.write_registers(address, payload, skip_encode=True, unit=1)
```

Comment: а что не получается?

Comment: я пытаюсь записывать как-то так, но как я понял это способ для записи 1 байта
`master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster(host='192.168.0.191', port=9761)
master.execute(slave=1, function_code=cst.WRITE_SINGLE_REGISTER, starting_address=0, quantity_of_x=8, output_value=data)`